# Could this cursor be optimized or rewritten for optimum performance?

Tags: sql-server, database, t-sql, cursor

There is a need to update all of our databases on our server and perform the same logic on each one.  The databases in question all follow a common naming scheme like CorpDB1, CorpDB2, etc.  Instead of creating a SQL Agent Job for each of the databases in question (over 50), I have thought about using a cursor to iterate over the list of databases and then perform some dynamic sql on each one.  In light of the common notion that cursors should be a last resort; could this be rewritten for better performance or written another way perhaps with the use of the undocumented [sp_MSforeachdb stored procedure](http://weblogs.sqlteam.com/joew/archive/2008/08/27/60700.aspx)?

```
DECLARE @db VARCHAR(100) --current database name
DECLARE @sql VARCHAR(1000) --t-sql used for processing on each database

DECLARE db_cursor CURSOR FAST_FORWARD FOR
    SELECT name
    FROM MASTER.dbo.sysdatabases
    WHERE name LIKE 'CorpDB%'
OPEN db_cursor
FETCH NEXT FROM db_cursor INTO @db
WHILE @@FETCH_STATUS = 0
BEGIN
    SET @sql = 'USE ' + @db +
    ' DELETE FROM db_table --more t-sql processing'
    EXEC(@sql)
    FETCH NEXT FROM db_cursor INTO @db
END
CLOSE db_cursor
DEALLOCATE db_cursor
```

Comment: `sp_msforeachdb` and `sp_msforeachtable` are both just wrappers for cursors anyways some performance difference should be minimal.

Comment: Heh go figure.. I never opened them up to see what they did but that does not surprise me.

Comment: I don't think you will upset the SQL-Gods by using a cursor like that. The precense of cursor will not bring your server to a halt, it's what you do with it and how often. In this case you will be looping through 50 rows. I think this is better than any alternatives that I can figure out.

Comment: Always useful to specify *version* of SQL Server.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Cursors are bad when they are used to tackle a set-based problem with procedural code. I don't think a cursor is necessarily a bad idea in your scenario.

When operations need to be run against multiple databases (backups, integrity checks, index maintenance, etc.), there's no issue with using a cursor. Sure, you could build a temp table that contains database names and loop through that...but it's still a procedural approach.

For your specific case, if you're not deleting rows in these tables based on some `WHERE` clause criteria, consider using `TRUNCATE TABLE` instead of `DELETE FROM`. Differences between the two operations explained [here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa260621%28v=SQL.80%29.aspx). Note that the user running `TRUNCATE TABLE` will need `ALTER` permission on the affected objects.

Comment: That's great information beargle that I will definitely keep in mind for future use.  In this particular instance, the delete statement will have a where clause.  I left it out for brevity.

Answer (score 2):

This will collect the set of delete statements and run them all in a single sequence. This is not necessarily going to be better performance-wise but just another way to skin the cat.

```
DECLARE @sql NVARCHAR(MAX); -- if SQL Server 2000, use NVARCHAR(4000)

SET @sql = N'';

SELECT @sql = @sql + N';DELETE ' + name + '..db_table -- more t-sql'
  FROM master.sys.databases
  WHERE name LIKE N'CorpDB%';

SET @sql = STUFF(@sql, 1, 1, '');

EXEC sp_executesql @sql;
```

You may consider building the string in a similar way inside your cursor instead of running `EXEC()` inside for each command. If you're going to continue using a cursor, use the following declaration:

```
DECLARE db_cursor CURSOR 
  LOCAL STATIC FORWARD_ONLY READ_ONLY
  FOR
```

This will have the least locking and no unnecessary tempdb usage.

Comment: I appreciate your alternative approach.  I wish I could mark both as possible answers!

Comment: Also if undocumented / unsupported aren't enough to dissuade you from using `sp_msforeachdb`, have a look at https://sqlblog.org/blogs/aaron_bertrand/archive/2010/12/29/a-more-reliable-and-more-flexible-sp-msforeachdb.aspx and http://www.mssqltips.com/sqlservertip/2201/making-a-more-reliable-and-flexible-spmsforeachdb/